# Java path in Linux

Tags: java, linux, path

I have a bit problem, and i dont seem to understand what is causing it.
i have a folder in my project, and in that folder i have a class, and i have a resource file (in this case jasper report).
but the only way i can access file is with absolute path or some path that starts from root of my project.

```
String path = "src/main/java/Views/LagerMain/lager.jrxml";
```

^^this works, both my class LagerController and lager.jrxml are under LagerMain folder, but when i try to do this :

```
String path = "lager.jrxml";
```

i have an error that file is not found. 
I tried googling this to have a better understanding but i found nothing.

Bottom line, why cant i access my file, from class when they are both on same place, why does not relative path work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the main class is in a different directory, then the program will try to access`lager.jrxml` there instead of the directory of the regular class.

**For regular-class directory**:

```
String path = new String(MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()
.getPath() + System.getProperty("line.separator") + "lager.jrxml");
```

If that doesn't work, try this:

```
// your directory
File f = new File("src");
File[] matchingFiles = f.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return name.startsWith("lager") && name.endsWith("jrxml");
    }
});
```

If you have more than one file with the name `lager.jrxml`, then this method will return both of them and you will need to use a `for` to cycle through them. Otherwise, you can just use

```
String path = new String(matchingFiles[0].getAbsolutePath())
```

**For main-class directory**:

```
String path = new String(System.getProperty("user.dir")
 + System.getProperty("line.separator") + "lager.jrxml");
```